# Find letter of the system drive of most recently attached VHD

Tags: windows, virtualbox, batch, script

There are scripts for finding letter of most recently attached VHD [here](https://superuser.com/questions/753460/how-to-properly-get-the-drive-letter-of-a-mounted-vhd-in-batch-script) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1165369/finding-the-drive-letter-of-the-most-recently-mounted-xvhd-or-vhd-file-in-batch). I use the following code to run from batch script:

```
FOR /f usebackq %%a in (`powershell -c "GET-DISKIMAGE %VIRTUAL_MACHINE_PATH% | GET-DISK | GET-PARTITION | GET-VOLUME | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DriveLetter"`) DO SET VIRTUAL_DISK_LETTER=%%a
echo %VIRTUAL_DISK_LETTER%
```

But in my case, I have an Windows Image and after attaching its virtual drive I often have 2 new volumes: one is "Microsoft reserved partition" of approximately 50Mb and a system partition with Windows itself. And in all (I suppose ) cases the "Microsoft reserved partition" comes first with letter, say `F`, and the system partition goes second, say with drive `H`. How to find exactly the letter of system partition?

**Update:** I suppose, the only way to do what I want is to check the size of the volume and that's fine for me. May be I need something like:

```
FOR /f usebackq %%a in (`powershell -c "GET-DISKIMAGE %VIRTUAL_MACHINE_PATH% | GET-DISK | GET-PARTITION | GET-VOLUME | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DriveLetter -ExpandProperty Size"`) DO (
    if %%a.size > 100000000(
        SET VIRTUAL_DISK_LETTER=%%a.letter
    )
)
echo %VIRTUAL_DISK_LETTER%
```

I think, I will doing it a lot of time, if someone may help me, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Also you could identify the letter by 1. label of partition inside (cmd: label, vol) 2. some kind of ID (GUID), where FAT IDs are like 1234-5678 hex numbers 3. known file inside.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with checking for `Windows` folder on the partition:

```
for /f usebackq %%a in (`powershell -c "GET-DISKIMAGE %VIRTUAL_MACHINE_PATH% | GET-DISK | GET-PARTITION | GET-VOLUME | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DriveLetter"`) do (
    if exist "%%a:\Windows\" (
        set VIRTUAL_DISK_LETTER=%%a
    )
)
if "%VIRTUAL_DISK_LETTER%"=="" (
  echo Error! Couldn't find virtual disk letter.
  exit /b -2
)
```